# Relativistic electron in electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Consider an electron in an electromagnetic field where $\overrightarrow{E}=E \hat{z}$, $E=1 Vm^{-1}$, $\overrightarrow{B}=B\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \hat{z}+B\frac{1}{2} \hat{x}$, $B=1.5T$. The electron starts at $(0, 0, 0)$ and with zero velocity.

1. Determine the energy of the electron after $1μs$.
2. Determine its distance from the $z$ axis at $1μs$.

I was assigned this question for homework. The professor told us that the values of the electric and the magnetic fields are huge, meaning we have to take relativity into accound, adding that this means that Newton's 2nd law becomes $$\frac{d}{dt} (\gamma m_0 \overrightarrow{v})=q(\overrightarrow{E}+\overrightarrow{v} \times \overrightarrow{B}).$$

If relativistic effects were not considered, this would be a rather standard problem, as Newton's law can be easily solved (it is a system of 3 linear first order differential equations) to determine $\overrightarrow{v}$. However, the introduction of the Lorentz factor into the momentum renders this much more difficult. The professor also told us that we could consider the velocity as the superposition of two velocities, one exclusively due to the electric field and one velocity on the $y$ axis (normal to both $\overrightarrow{E}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$). However, this would imply that there is no velocity on the $x$ axis, which seems to be false, as the existence of a magnetic field on $z$ means that the velocity cannot possibly be contained on the $yz$ plane. Futheremore, I don't see how viewing velocity as a superposition of two other velocities can help given the non-linearity of the Lorentz factor.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Have you calculated the speed after $1\ \mu$ s ignoring $B$ ? You'll find it's non-relativistic (<< *c*). Incidentally, $E=$ 1 V m$^{-1}$ would usually be thought of as a weak field.

On the other hand, $B=1.5\ $T is a strong magnetic field, but it won't affect the electron's speed!